# Blog posts pagination not working

Tags: posts, pagination, navigation

I have been debugging this but I cannot seem to find what's wrong. An extra eye would help!
I am trying to add pagination on my blog posts. Here is the code

On `home.php`

```
 <?php

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ( $total_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <div class="pagination col-12 text-center mt-3">

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

And on `template-tags.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'the_posts_navigation' ) ) :
function the_posts_navigation() {

    global $wp_query;

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => get_permalink() . 'page/%#%' . '/', 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => return_svg( 'arrow-left' ),
        'next_text' => return_svg( 'arrow-right' ),
    ) );
}
endif;
```

Any idea what seems to be wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: 1) Are you sure your blog page uses `home.php` template? 2) On `template-tags.php` you check if the_post_navigation exists, but it always exists, because it's wordpress function. Do you call it if it exists?

Comment: Hi @anton , yes blog page uses `home.php`. I am trying to make global pagination. What would you suggest? Even if I remove the if exists condition, pagination won't still show.

Comment: I don't think problem related to the_posts_navigation(), because it's native wp function. And I can't see your pages full code.  Settings -> Reading -> Your home page displays is set to "Your latest posts"?

Comment: Oh, `home.php` is automatically used on  the posts page. This is my reference:
https://wphierarchy.com/

@anton, I still cannot see why the pagination is not showing. Blogs are showing though. Something wrong with my `if` statement on displaying pagination?

Comment: In your first code, you don't need to check total pages (the same check goes inside already), unless you need to hide wrapper div for navigation. Try to echo something in your home.php, just to make sure you see it on your home page. I asked this before, because home.php is used when "Your latest posts" is checked.

Comment: No it is not checked @anton. In my case `home.php` is used on a separate static page.

Comment: Actually not. From wp website about home.php: "If you do not set WordPress to use a static front page, this template is used to show latest posts.". So I think your blog page just uses another template. `front-page.php` if you have, or `index.php`. Try to use `the_posts_navigation()` there.

Comment: I see. `index.php` uses `the_posts_navigation()`. I revisited the Reading Settings and set the `Blog pages show at most` to `6` since my `posts_per_page` is `6` too. Pagination is now showing.

Comment: Do you theme have front-page.php file?

Comment: No, it doesn't have @anton

Comment: add your index.php code to your answer please

Comment: Hey @anton, it is working properly now. Just had to set the posts to 6 per page :)

Comment: If you manually set posts_per_page, try to use `get_option( 'posts_per_page' )` to be able change it later on Reading Settings page. But glad your problem solved. I will add my comment as an answer, ok?

Comment: Yes! Add it as your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common problem of similar questions I see on WPSE - contributors confused about template hierarchy.
In your case,
it's better to check `Common Wordpress template files` section [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#common-wordpress-template-files)
These items most important for your question:

**front-page.php**
The front page template is always used as the site front page if it exists, regardless of what settings on Admin > Settings > Reading.
**home.php**
The home page template is the front page by default. If you do not set WordPress to use a static front page, this template is used to show latest posts.
**index.php**
The main template file. It is required in all themes.

So, `front-page.php` used first, then `home.php`(if it exists in your theme and Admin>Settings>Reading is set to "Your latest posts"), then `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks much @anton!